# writing a iiop client in order to dynamically configure a cisco appliance

Tags: iiop

My firm is about to purchase a cisco appliance named dcm.
It's only api is a limited snmp or iiop.
I want to create a simple gui that will help my users configure certain fields on the dcm with ease.

I have done this before with snmp but have zero expirience with iiop.

I preffer to implement with either java or python.

I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction (java/python, recommended libraries etc.)

BTW i saw a lot of mentions about rmi-iiop but I'm pretty sure it's irrelevant. ( am I right?)

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't CISCO provide some documentation how to do this? Probably you need a CORBA implementation for your client like R2CORBA, TAOX11, JacORB

Comment: Yes they offer the api but my question is how to implement the app that communicates with the device (will it be correct to call the app a cobra client?)

Comment: Yes, that is at least a CORBA client, but when the CISCO API also had a feature to call back to your client you will be implicitly also a CORBA server. What kind of application do you want to make and what are your requirements in terms of portabiliy, would it be a regular client app, or more a website kind of app?

Comment: Why am I a server? I thought the protocol is a request-response protocol... Regarding the portability i would preffer a web appllication for the user.

Comment: I don't know the IDL definition from CISCO but it could be that there is a callback feature so that the CISCO device calls you back when there is a change, if there is no support like that you are a pure client. For a web app, check R2CORBA as CORBA implementation, that can easily be integrated into Ruby on Rails to create a web app.

Comment: Ok thank you. Actually we use Java for web development. The problem is whenever I look for Java library all I get is rmi-iiop and I think it's irrelevant (am I wrong?).

Comment: Look at JacORB as Java CORBA implementation